# I would like to have a copy of all the partitions of primary drive to a secondary drive

Tags: partitioning

This is the command:

```
sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sfdisk --force /dev/sdb
```

It fails because permission is denied and the entire error message looks like this:

```
/dev/sdb: Permission denied
sfdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb read-write
Warning: extended partition does not start at a cylinder boundary.
DOS and Linux will interpret the contents differently.
```

I already tried formatting the sdb drive with disk utility or even removing the format and leaving it as unallocated space but nothing succeeded.
How should I execute it?
Thank you :)

PS: Ubuntu 12.04 are used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo sfdisk -d /dev/sda | sudo sfdisk --force /dev/sdb` should fix the ´permission denied'. The 2nd part needs to be with the correct permissions too (the pipe cancels the previous sudo.

The comment about the warning: this warning should only be relevant if you had some old OS installed alongside ubuntu that cares about cylinder boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the dd command instead.

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: I would too... but he wants to copy the partition table: "sfdisk has four (main) uses: list the size of a partition, list the partitions on a device, check the partitions on a device, and - very dangerous - repartition a device." He is after the dangerous part ;) So your dd command probably should look like this: `dd if=/dev/sda of=/tmp/sda-mbr.bin bs=512 count=1` and for restoring `dd if= sda-mbr.bin of=/dev/sdb bs=1 count=64 skip=446 seek=446`

Comment: No I am not backing up. This is just a step for creating raid-1